# Post data to retrieve information from SQL Query in IOS

Tags: php, ios, sql, iphone, ios7

Im new to IOS and I am trying to obtain data from a php file in Json format. The way that I would like to obtain this data is by sending information from the app to the php sql query. I have tried the following:

IOS:

```
        NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"ID",newsID];
        NSLog(myRequestString); 

        NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/file.php"]];

        [request setHTTPMethod: @"REQUEST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
        [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; //Or async request
        NSError *error=nil;

        NSArray *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:&error];
```

PHP:

```
$query="SELECT news_description FROM newsTable WHERE newsID = ".$_REQUEST['ID'].";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
```

I have researched some ideas but unfortunately it does not send the information to the php file. I have tried changing $_REQUEST to $_POST, also I created a variable in my php file to store $_POST but no luck. Any suggestions? Please help! Thank you!

Comment: I have googled different solutions but unfortunately it does not post the information in order to complete the query, any suggestions?? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JWURLConnection on GitHub](https://github.com/julian-weinert/JWURLConnection). If you prefer to write your own code, you can look at the source code.

**EDIT** To give you more information: You are creating a plain HTTP request in your code. And the HTTP body your are sending is absolutely **not** HTTP compliant. The `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type has to follow very specific rules defined by RFC.

As I looked at your code again I saw an issue. You are missing an equals sign:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",@"ID",newsID]
                              ^^^
```

I would recommend to read the RFC specifications or, as stated before, follow the code implemented in the mentioned class, it follows the rules strictly.

If you can't fix the issue using the class you'll probably have an issue in the PHP script, so you would have to provide more informations about the script.

**EDIT II**

As I looked at your code *once again* I could find another issue. You are not setting the request method correctly. Here you set

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"REQUEST"];
```

which is not a valid HTTP method! If you want post, you have to set it to `@"POST"` or for get `@"GET"`, for head `@"HEAD"` and so on, see [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've looked into it but still getting an error when posting on the php file

Comment: Can you provide more informations on the "error" you get? You might have an issue in your PHP file...!

Comment: Thank you for the update, I tried what you suggested but no luck. Unfortunately there is no error from the php file. The php file just returns a null value as if the information being sent is not being sent and thus the query cannot run properly. If i manually change the query to value I' am sending it provides me with the result I'm looking for. I guess my issue here is that I'm trying to use this http request as if i would in JAVA namevaluepair (I am not sure if you are familiar with this), when i tried it there it works fine with no issues.

Comment: See my edit again, you are using a non existent HTTP method :)

Comment: you sir is the best!! Thank you that was it! it took me forever to figure it out but it was exactly that! thank you again!!